# Sending array from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, ajax

Here's the values I am sending to the PHP script from the Javascript:

```
$('.verdi_knapp').click(function() {
$(this).siblings().removeClass("aktiv_verdi"); // ta vekk aktiv på de andre alternativene
$(this).addClass("aktiv_verdi"); // sett denne til aktiv

var min_id = $(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]; 
var aktuelle_verdier = []

$('.aktiv_verdi').each(function() {
  aktuelle_verdier.push($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1]);
})
console.log("disse verdiene skal vi spørre etter", aktuelle_verdier)

      $.ajax({
        url: "oyvind_liste.php", 
        data: {aktuelle_verdier}, 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){
          console.log(result);
     }});
```

This is the PHP script which queries a set of values from an SQL database and prints them to the console in the javascript:

```
$ids = $_GET['aktuelle_verdier'];
$value = implode(", ", $ids);

$antall = count($_GET);

$sql = "SELECT `art_id` 
        FROM `art_has_verdi` 
        WHERE `verdi_id` IN (".$value.") 
        GROUP BY `art_id` HAVING COUNT(*)=".$antall.";";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$arter_igjen = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
array_push($arter_igjen, $row['art_id']);
}
echo json_encode($arter_igjen);
```

What I am trying to find out next is how to send this array: $arter_igjen, which contains a set of IDs, to another page where I can run a query to the database for all the data containing these IDs and print them out in a list.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "oyvind_liste.php", 
    data: {aktuelle_verdier: aktuelle_verdier}, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
 }});
```

Please check data Paramter in ajax call. You forgot to pass key in JSON.

Comment: The two documents already work perfectly fine in passing values. @Bhargav Ruparara

Comment: Please try to pass sample JSON data like "data: {test : 'test' }". if you're getting in PHP page then there must something wrong with the array you're passing. @ØyvindHjartnes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you like after ajax return you clone the window and in new one window you will make some new searches, but on the current one will be generate a log. In cas I'm understand you right, then why don't try to generate form on fly by with returned data end post it to the _blank window.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "oyvind_liste.php", 
    data: {aktuelle_verdier}, 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){

      // Here you have to generate the form on fly
      // Include hidden fields, containing your result data
      // and finally send form with action some new.php on blank_ target

      console.log(result);
 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other page contains code like in this one (not in a class or function), you can just include it (include_once "..."), but it is not recommended that you just keep scripts like that.

Instead, **encapsulate** your code (put it within functions and classes). This will allow you to freely insert your scripts (include_once "...") and call these functions or create classes that will work.

Also, try to avoid too many **http requests**. If that list of ids won't be needed, do all of the work in the php scripts and return the needed result.

There are a few issues with your code. If you are just starting with PHP I would suggest you read:

1. [PDO: Creating a connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)
2. [PDO with prepared statements (prevents SQL injections)](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
3. User-defined functions (I don't have enough reputation to put the link. Search: "w3schools php 5 functions")